# showForm, Command Action, and going-back

Tags: forms, codenameone

Going "back" from a form doesn't take me to the previous form but back to the main form. What am I doing wrong? Here's more detail:

I have a `Command` that takes you from the main form of my app to a "human setup" form. From that form if you click on a certain multibutton I go to another form (MaintenanceLevel) like this:

```
protected void onHumanSetup_MultiButtonMaintenanceAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    // Invoke the next level of form
    showForm("MaintenanceLevel", null);
}
```

In the "MaintenanceLevel" form I have an `Action` set to `Back`, but when I click the menu bar to go back I end up back on the main-form and not the "human setup" where I want to be.

**Edit:**
Things have got a little worse!! Now when I go back in to view the Commands for my MaintenanceLevel form it's empty: it's forgetting the command I've entered :(

Here is my `command` setting for MaintenanceLevel form:
[image]

Comment: Did you add your own back command or are you using builtin back? How are you adding the commands to the form?

Comment: Using the built in back command by clicking the command property of the form in the gui editor. In there I select Action to be Back and also click the Back check box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define a back command. Remove it. Codename One automatically creates back commands for you.

The usage for this option is when you create a Button and place it within the form, then you want it to behave as a back button effectively (e.g. cancel button).

Comment: Ah I see - leave it blank. I think I always have been adding them because in the GUI designer there appears to be no menu. Thanks @Shai!!

Comment: Is there an official way to set up Cancel and Done menu buttons?

Comment: There is no standard way to do that but there are lots of ways you can achieve that depending on how you want this to look/behave